# Bulk update huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, bulk

I have a table that has 26 columns with a couple of thousand records.
Is there a way to bulk update this table?

Right now I just do a standard update on each column that needs updating.
E.g.

```
update mytbl
set col1 = replace(....)

update mytbl
set col1 = col1 + "xyz"

update mytbl
set col2 = "test..."
```

I know that for each record the statements above will update the column for all records first before going to next column(s).

I'm looking for a "quick bulk update" as this is taking too long.

Thanks

Comment: Are the criteria for each column change different? eg, only update column1 when x is tue, column2 when y.. or are the criteria the same accross all columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this structure:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET col1 = REPLACE(col1.....),
    col2 = 'some value'
```

Comment: can this be accomplished:

update myTable
set col1 = replace(col1...),
    col1 = col1 + "some value"

Comment: Error return when trying to update a col1 more than once in a multicol update as suggested by ck..

A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause.

Comment: @Ernesto - Can you post your SQL (edit your question to add it) and the full error message. It would help to find the problem.

Comment: @Ernesto - if you want to update a column multiple times, you have to do it all in one statement: `SET col1 = replace(col1...) + 'some value' .. any other operations ...`

Answer (score 1):

1 - A couple thousand records x 26 fields isn't huge :)

2 - Either use the multiple-field update syntax ck suggests, or insert it into a new table which may be faster:

```
SELECT (REPLACE(col1...)) as Col1,
       'Some Value' as Col2,
       ...
INTO MyNewTable
FROM MyOldTable
```

Comment: at least 600 000 records.
I do multiple updates on one column until the data is in the format that is required.
E.G. urlcol might have value http://www.test.com/tess/1234/zap.php
I then do an update to remove the http:// part
then
another update to remove anything after .com
result in urlcol is then www.test.com

Some other columns i can only update from info from other columns

Comment: As mentioned by you that the operation will execute on 1 table. Which means the query will not have any join. Then don't worry. JNK - "INTO MyNewTable" I think, we can directly execute update statementon the target table without intrducing a second table ?

Comment: i ran a test on about 1.2million reocrds and it took 19minutes to complete.

Comment: did you try to disable the indexes ? and then start ur test and restore afterwards

Comment: @Ernesto - based on your comments, it sounds like you are doing multi-valued logic on URLs and other strings.  Try putting that into a UDF and running the update with the UDF in the new value

Answer (score 0):

These advices are more useful for much bigger number of records, but might help anyway:
1. Use multifield update as suggested by ck

1. If it is possible lock the table for exclusive access during the update.
2. Disable all of the indexes. Restore them after update finished.

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of following points.

1. You can use SQL Profiler to to check that whether any trigger is doing something during your updation process.
2. You can disable the indexes. Run your test now and finally restore it.